# editingEnabled Property is always return as True for feature layers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, feature-layer, hosted-feature-layer

I have hosted two feature layers in ArcGIS Online 10.8 and consumed it as portal items in my webmap application using ESRI Javascript API 4.19. I have enabled editing for one feature layer and not enabled the editing for another feature layer since it is read-only.

I shared these two layers to an user account (named 'test_user') which has the role of 'users'. when I logged into the webmap application using 'test_user' account, I am able to retrieve these two layers from portal items.

But when looking at 'editingEnabled' Property of both layers, it returns as **True**. But actually for one feature layer, it should return as **False**. Even if I untick the '**Editing Enabled**' option for hosted feature layers in ArcGIS Online, it's still return as **True** in the application.

```
view.map.layers.forEach(function (layer, index) {
  console.log(layer.editingEnabled); });
```

Is there a method to get the edit access of feature layer in JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript - that `editingEnabled` is always true.

However, you can take advantage of the sourceJSON property, which includes all the REST metadata for the service.

Specifically, `layer.sourceJSON.capabilities` will show the available capabilities. For example, if editing is enabled on a hosted feature layer (depending on what other editing options have been set):
`Create,Delete,Query,Update,Editing,Sync`

And if the editing is not enabled, something like:
`Query,Sync`

Comment: Thanks Bjorn. It works as expected !